# a heap with n elements that supports Insert and Extract-Min, Which of the following tasks can you achieve in O(logn) time?

Tags: data-structures

For the following questions

> Question 3
> You are given a heap with n elements that supports Insert and Extract-Min. Which of the following tasks can you achieve in O(logn) time?
>
> - Find the median of the elements stored in the heap.
> - Find the fifth-smallest element stored in the heap.
> - Find the largest element stored in the heap.
> - Find the median of the elements stored in theheap.

Why is "Find the largest element stored in the heap."not correct, my understanding here is that you can use logN time to go to the bottom of the heap, and one of the element there must be the largest element.

"Find the fifth-smallest element stored in the heap." this should take constant time right, because you only need to go down 5 layers at most?

"Find the median of the elements stored in the heap. " should this take O(n) time? because we extract min for the n elements to get a sorted array, and take o(1) to find the median of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is "Find the largest element stored in the heap."not correct, my understanding here is that you can use logN time to go to the bottom of the heap, and one of the element there must be the largest element.

The lowest level of the heap contains half of the elements. More correctly, half of the elements of the heap are leaves--have no children. The largest element in the heap is one of those. Finding the largest element of the heap, then, will require that you examine n/2 items. Except that the heap only supports *insert* and *extract-min*, so you end up having to call *extract-min* on every element. Finding the largest element will take O(n log n) time.

> "Find the fifth-smallest element stored in the heap." this should take constant time right, because you only need to go down 5 layers at most?

This can be done in log(n) time. Actually 5*log(n) because you have to call *extract-min* five times. But we ignore constant factors. However it's not constant time because the complexity of *extract-min* depends on the size of the heap.

> "Find the median of the elements stored in the heap." should this take O(n) time? because we extract min for the n elements to get a sorted array, and take o(1) to find the median of it?

The median is the middle element. So you only have to remove n/2 elements from the heap. But removing an item from the heap is a log(n) operation. So the complexity is O(n/2 log n) and since we ignore constant factors in algorithmic analysis, it's O(n log n).

Comment: Hi Jim, thanks for the explanation, but why are there n/2 nodes at the leaf of the heap, shouldn't it be 2^(logN)?

Comment: @JackDuan You're right in the general. I often think in terms of full heaps, where the number of leaf nodes is (n/2)-1.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the running times are of the operations insert and extract-min. In traditional heaps, both take ϴ(log n) time. However, in finger-tree-based heaps, only insert takes ϴ(log n) time, while extract-min takes O(1) time. There, you can find the fifth smallest element in O(5) = O(1) time and the median in O(n/2) = O(n) time. You can also find the largest element in O(n) time.